# D3 not able to show line

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a scatter plot in which I need to fit a line to the plot. I load the data with an ajax call as JSON.
I just can't seem to get the line to show. When I inspect elements I can see the path but nothing shows.

Here is a JSFiddle with the problem:
I've commented the ajax part out and hard coded the data I get back.

[JSFiddle with missing line](http://jsfiddle.net/24qfo4bL/3/)

And I am guessing the problem is somewhere around line 299-318 here:

```
 linegroup = main.append('g')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(0,0)')
        .attr('class', 'main myline');

    var line = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function (d) {
        return d.x;
    })
        .y(function (d) {
        return d.y;
    });

    linegroup.selectAll("path")
        .data([data.line])
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("d", line)
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .attr("stroke", "#000")
        .attr("stroke-width", 5);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to figure it out, sorry to bother you.

The problem was I had forgot to add the scales to the line so it ended up way below the page ended.

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function (d) { return x(d.x); })
        .y(function(d) { return y(d.y); });
```